# Removing collisions from a link using parameter passing

Tags: ros-noetic, gazebo-11, collision

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to load some static models into a world. I would like them to not cause any collisions, so I am trying to remove them using the tutorial here: http://sdformat.org/tutorials?tut=param_passing_tutorial&cat=specification&

Has this been implemented in sdf 1.7 and the Gazebo release for ROS Noetic?

The models are showing up with the collision elements present.

I am running the latest release of ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 20.04.5

My code is attached.[C:\fakepath\test.world](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/16705178633672165.world)

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28629/removing-collisions-from-a-link-using-parameter-passing/) by [Gavriel-CTO](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/120232/gavriel-cto/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Parameter passing is only implemented in libsdformat 10 and later. I assume you're using Gazebo 11 (from the tag on the question), and that uses libsdformat9. However, I believe you can install libsdformat10 or later, run `ign sdf -p` on the input file and get an output that has the param-passing changes applied.

---

Originally posted by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) with karma: 704 on 2022-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gavriel-CTO](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/120232/gavriel-cto/) on 2022-12-11**:
Correct. Where is the documentation connecting ROS, Gazebo, SDFormat version number and libsdformat version number? I couldn't find any definitive resource that would contain the kind of information you provided in this answer. Thanks!

**Comment by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) on 2022-12-12**:
http://sdformat.org/tutorials?tut=roadmap&cat=developers&#libsdformat-releases